# How to calculate the aging provided two dates?

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat, date-difference

I'm trying to implement this logic in my app where I have to calculate the aging process.

I will be getting the date along with time dynamically as a string.
For instance, it will be like following

```
String due_date = "2016-03-27 00:00:00"
```

To find the number of days between two dates, I have the following code

```
SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH-mm-ss");
Date dt1 = format1.parse("due_date");
```

But the problem is that I'm unable to do so because I'm getting a parse exception.

So,

1. How can I be able to parse a string due_date?
2. How can I be able to subtract current date from due_date to get the number of days between two dates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can i be able to parse a string due_date?

You should use this format:

```
SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date dueDate = format1.parse(due_date);
```

> How can I be able to subtract current date from due_date to get the number of days between two days?

you should write method like:

```
public static int getDaysBetweenDates(Date fromDate, Date dueDate) {
    return (int) ((dueDate.getTime() - fromDate.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24L));
}
```

and use it like this:

```
String from_date = "2016-03-26 00:00:00";
String due_date = "2016-03-27 00:00:00";

SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date fromDate = format1.parse(from_date);
Date dueDate = format1.parse(due_date);

System.out.println(getDaysBetweenDates(fromDate, dueDate));//prints "1"
```

Comment: im getting `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2016-03-27 00:00:00" `

Comment: fixed an answer, it was a typo

Comment: glad it helped! Welcome to the Stackoverflow

Comment: Thank you. it matters a lot!

Comment: @user22312412 Unfortunately this simple solution is not perfect. It will fail around dates with daylight-saving switch by one full day (change between winter and summer time).

Comment: so what could be a better solution?

Comment: you can use Java 8 Date api (or Joda time)

Answer (score 0):

> Two ways to get total days between two dates

- Using Date class

`public static int getDaysDifference(Date fromDate,Date toDate)
               {
            if(fromDate==null||toDate==null)
                 return 0;
            return (int)( (toDate.getTime() - fromDate.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        }`

- using Calendar

`public static int getDaysDifference(Calendar calendar1,Calendar calendar2)
        {
            if(calendar1==null||calendar2==null)
                return 0;
            return (int)( (calendar2.getTimeInMillis() - calendar1.getTimeInMillis()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        }`

To format date follow @Cootri answer. :)